# RadDatePicker add hours

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, telerik, datepicker

I need to set a RadDatePicker to a set hour interval 23:59:59

I have two DatePickers one is the Start Date and the second is the End Date. If the user was to pick 9/11/2013 9/11/2013 it won't show any data because the data has happened after 12:00:00am and the date selected is 9/11/2013 12:00:00AM. So in order to resolve this I would like to do a

RadDatePicker.Hour = 23:59:59

So I have tried this a few different ways and I keep getting errors and I am struggling with syntax at this point.

This is happening in a SelectedDataChange Event in the date picker. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the hours on a RadDatePicker.
Just add a day to the End Date when using the range:

```
DateTime start = (DateTime)rdpStart.SelectedDate;
DateTime end = ((DateTime)rdpEnd.SelectedDate).AddDays(1);
```